# Processing POST request of an audio file

Tags: web, raku, cro

What is the equivalent POST request using:

- [Cro](https://cro.services/)
- ["HTTP::Tiny"](https://raku.land/zef:jjatria/HTTP::Tiny)
- Other libraries

for this curl shell command:

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.someservice.com/v1/ \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  --form file=@/path/to/file/audio.mp3 \
  --form transformer=trans-2 \
  --form format=text
```

I tried following the examples in
["Cro::HTTP::Client"](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-client)
without success...

(See the example starting with `my $resp = await Cro::HTTP::Client.post: 'we.love.pand.as/pandas',`)

---

### Update

Here is a working example using [the answer of @jja](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75929162/) that requires to:

- Have an OpenAI (account and) authorization key
- Download one of the MP3 files from [here](https://github.com/antononcube/Raku-WWW-OpenAI/tree/main/resources)

  - Or use another MP3 file with speech recording.

```
use HTTP::Tiny;


my $fileName = $*HOME ~ '/Downloads/HelloRaccoonsEN.mp3';


say .<content>.decode given HTTP::Tiny.post: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions',
        headers => { authorization => "Bearer {%*ENV<OPENAI_API_KEY>}" },
        content => {
            file        => $fileName.IO,
            model       => 'whisper-1',
            format      => 'text'
        };
```

Here is the expected result:

```
# {"text":"Raku practitioners around the world, eat more onions!"}
```

Comment: Does it have to be `Cro`?  Does something like `HTTP::Tiny` or `HTTP::Tinyish`  work for you?

Comment: @jubilatious1 Any solution would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how that would look with HTTP::Tiny:

```perl
say .<content>.decode given HTTP::Tiny.post: 'https://httpbin.org/anything',
    headers => { authorization => 'Bearer TOKEN' },
    content => {
        file        => 'path/to/your/file'.IO,
        transformer => 'trans-2',
        format      => 'text'
    }
```

If you set the `content` to a hash it will default to use a multipart form encoding, and if any of the values supports a `slurp` method (in this case, the IO::Path you get by calling `IO` on your path) that will be used to get the value before sending.

And the output so you can inspect what was sent:

```perl
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {
    "file": "data:application/octet-stream;base64,...."
  }, 
  "form": {
    "format": "text", 
    "transformer": "trans-2"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN", 
    "Content-Length": "...", 
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"VfaSnFoNawbxJQnMbtJr\"", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "HTTP::Tiny/0.2.5 Raku", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-deadbeef-deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "method": "POST", 
  "origin": "123.45.67.89", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}
```

Comment: Works great-- thanks! (Just tried with OpenAI audio transcription.)

Comment: We're all busy, and Anton is doing great stuff, and this solution worked for them. But while he didn't have time/motivation to figure out the mistake he was making with Cro, I want later readers to understand that this SO was near certainly nothing to do with Cro, which works fine for Anton's case. We know this because, while Anton didn't provide an [MRE] in their Q, and the best anyone could do with the info in Anton's "my attempt has the following two parts" comment on jnthn's answer is guess which code Anton used, I dug around and quickly found a basic coding bug, nothing to do with Cro.

Comment: Oh, for sure. No issue or limitation with Cro was reported, so I don't think there is any. Since there was a comment suggesting that non-Cro based solutions (= translations from curl) were welcome, I figured this would be useful to have.

Comment: @jja Thanks again for providing the "HTTP::Tiny" solution! I refactored ["WWW::OpenAI"](https://raku.land/zef:antononcube/WWW::OpenAI) to use it as its primary [OpenAI](https://openai.com) access method.

Answer (score 7):

It would have been helpful to know what you attempted in order to work out how to correct it. Anyway, I'd expect the example request to look something like this in Cro:

```
my $resp = await Cro::HTTP::Client.post: 'https://api.someservice.com/v1/',
    headers => [ Authorization => 'Bearer TOKEN' ],
    content-type => 'multipart/form-data',
    body => [
        transformer => 'trans-2',
        format => 'text',
        Cro::HTTP::Body::MultiPartFormData::Part.new(
            headers => [Cro::HTTP::Header.new(
                name => 'Content-type',
                value => 'audio/mpeg'
            )],
            name => 'file',
            filename => 'audio.mp3',
            body-blob => slurp('/path/to/file/audio.mp3', :bin)
        )
    ];
```

I'm not sure exactly what mime type `curl` goes with, so it may slightly differ from what `curl` does in that regard.

Comment: "It would have been helpful to know what you attempted in order to work out how to correct it." -- Yeah, I should have. For what is worth, my attempt has the following two parts: [part1](https://github.com/antononcube/Raku-WWW-OpenAI/blob/main/lib/WWW/OpenAI.rakumod#L99) and [part2](https://github.com/antononcube/Raku-WWW-OpenAI/blob/main/lib/WWW/OpenAI.rakumod#L629).

Comment: @AntonAntonov Your links don't make sense to me. For example, the part 2 one is to a blank line right now. The latest commits to those files are marked as 2 days old by GH but your comment above is marked "yesterday" by SO. I'm SO confused!

Comment: @raiph Yeah, the links were pointing to the "previous" not working implementation I had. At this point I have implemented the suggestions by Jonathan given in this answer. I still cannot successfully get OpenAI to accept/process the POST message (I am constructing.) I will provide a more detailed description in an update of my question. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) I did not want to formulate the original question to be about making an audio file POST to OpenAI, since working on an answer would require having an auth key (in order to use OpenAI's web API.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov I guess my humor didn't translate. My point was that I poked around the commit history and saw no way for anyone to sensibly guess what code you really meant. And your replies haven't helped. So, still stumbling in the dark, but still trying to be helpful, I *do* see what is clearly a bug [here](https://github.com/antononcube/Raku-WWW-OpenAI/blob/e78388bbacad97f9154b0ab586f8e007632fb078/lib/WWW/OpenAI.rakumod#L653). Is that relevant?

Comment: @raiph Thank you for your comments! The bug you pointed out is relevant, but I simply have not succeeded to use Cro for OpenAI audio transcriptions. And since (1) I spent too much time trying to use Cro, (2) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75929162/14163984) works, and (3) my implementation using `curl` works, the Cro solution is much less important now.

Comment: OK. We're all busy, and Anton has a solution for their needs, which is the main thing. But in case anyone reading this is interested in *Cro*, and thinking it might be problematic, I'd like you to know that this SO isn't about that. Anton had unfortunately written `:$body` when they meant `:@body` (which mistake wasn't caught because they had declared both `$body` and `@body` variables). The SO norm for a question that's ultimately about a typo is to close it. But it now has an accepted answer. In sum, it's safe to presume Cro wasn't the problem and was just a red herring in this case.

Comment: @raiph Well... fixing that bug did not make my (current) Cro solution work. (I tried some other versions of it before and after posting the question here.) The minimal reproducible example requires having an OpenAI account -- I thought that is _not_ a SO norm.

Comment: While it's not ideal that someone might need an account to reproduce, the correct presumption is you've made a(nother) coding error, which wouldn't need an account. Indeed I see other such possible problems but I guess it's moot. I just wanted readers to be clear the problem is almost certainly not Cro, just some buggy code, but it's not obvious where to look in your module to nail it down. So it seems we'll not get to the bottom of things through this SO. Perhaps you'll come back to it one day, or post another SO with an MRE, or someone else will figure out what went wrong. I'll stop now! 

Comment: @raiph No need "to stop" ! :) It is in my TODO list to make an update with proper example code and related audio files. I hope I will do it by the end of the week.

Comment: Why files, plural? Surely a "proper" example would be jnthn's code, with not a single character changed, just the file that you test and confirm does not work using it. Perhaps I'm missing something, but even if I am, I still presume that the only productive example, given that Cro's lead author has written this answer, will be one that is an exact duplicate of his 16 lines of code apart from *minimal* differences (surely no more than 5 lines max?), with commentary, copiously justifying and explaining each change to jnthn's code. YMMV, but I'm hoping to avoid you or others wasting time. 

Comment: @raiph Finally, I updated my question with a working example.

Answer (score 5):

Using **Raku**'s [HTTP::Tinyish](https://raku.land/zef:skaji/HTTP::Tinyish) module

I've had very good luck downloading bioinformatic data from the European Bioinformatics Institute (EBI/Ensembl) using `HTTP::Tinyish`. Maybe the `POST` code below will work for you?

```perl
use HTTP::Tinyish;

my $http = HTTP::Tinyish.new(agent => "Mozilla/4.0");

my $server = 'https://rest.ensembl.org';
my $ext = '/archive/id';
my %response = $http.post: $server ~ $ext, 
  headers => { 
    'Content-type' => 'application/json',
    'Accept' => 'application/json'
  },
  content => '{ "id" : ["ENSG00000157764", "ENSG00000248378"] }';

die "Failed: " ~ %response<status> ~ "\n" ~ %response<content> ~ "\n" unless %response<success>; 


"\n1.________\n\n".put; #json output
use JSON::Fast <immutable>;
# .put for to-json(from-json(%response<content>));


"\n2.________\n\n".put; #below provides sorted output:
use PrettyDump;
for ( %response<content> ) {
  my $pretty = PrettyDump.new;
  put $pretty.dump: from-json(%response<content>);
};


"\n3.________\n\n".put; #below provides very compact `.raku` output:
# .say for from-json(%response<content>).raku;
```

Sample Output (version 2, `PrettyDump` only):

```perl
2.________


List=(
    Map=(
            :assembly("GRCh38"),
            :id("ENSG00000157764"),
            :is_current("1"),
            :latest("ENSG00000157764.14"),
            :peptide(Any),
            :possible_replacement(List=()),
            :release("109"),
            :type("Gene"),
            :version(14)
    ),
    Map=(
            :assembly("GRCh38"),
            :id("ENSG00000248378"),
            :is_current("1"),
            :latest("ENSG00000248378.1"),
            :peptide(Any),
            :possible_replacement(List=()),
            :release("109"),
            :type("Gene"),
            :version(1)
    )
)
```

Comment-out/un-comment the various returns (above), until you find one that suits your needs.

Comment: @AntonAntonov according to the `HTTP::Tinyish` docs, to receive binary back (like an mp3 file), add the parameter `bin => True` to your `%response` hash declaration line. HTH.

Comment: I upvoted this answer  -- I did not know about "HTTP::Tinyish", or considered non-Cro solutions. That said, ultimately this answer was not useful to me. (I.e. to have a successful upload of an audio file to OpenAI.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Interesting, wondering if a Github issue should be filed? After all, binary is binary.

Comment: See my question update with a working solution. If you have an OpenAI auth key then it should not be too expensive to run that code or similar... (Say, based on "HTTP::Tinyish".)

Comment: @AntonAntonov so `HTTP::Tinyish` should work. Maybe @shoichi (or  even @miyagawa) have suggestions going forward? Best Regards.